# C# class mapping for System.Text.Json deserialization

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I am writing C# to interface with a third party API. I'm having issues mapping a particular response to a class.

The doco for the method says the response will be:

```
{
    <text>:[{   /* driver ID */
        "t":<uint>, /* time of binding/unbinding*/
        "u":<long>  /* unit ID if binding, 0 if unbinding */
    }],
    ...
}
```

An example of the response is: `{"2534":[{"t":1711353044,"u":10568}]}`.
I've defined the Response class and the subclass as:

```
public class GetDriverBindingsResponse : IWialonApiRequestObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of bindings.  The key is a Driver Id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<DriverUnitBinding>>? Bindings { get; set; }
}

public class DriverUnitBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// time of binding/unbinding
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("t")]
    public uint Time { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// unit ID if binding, 0 if unbinding
    /// </summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("u")]
    public long UnitId { get; set; }
}
```

However, when deserializing, the Bindings collection is null. Even a simple test fails:

```
string test = "{\"2534\":[{\"t\":1711353044,\"u\":10568}]}";
GetDriverBindingsResponse? x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GetDriverBindingsResponse>(test);
Console.WriteLine(x.Bindings?.Count);
```

What do I need to change for this class to deserialize correctly?

Comment: You need to deserialize to dictionary directly, not a your model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have an empty property name. The serializer assumes that the JSON you are deserializing ***is*** the type that you are providing.

In your case, you can deserialize the JSON as a `Dictionary<string, List<DriverUnitBinding>>` directly though:

```cs
string test = @"{""2534"":[{""t"":1711353044,""u"":10568}]}";
var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<DriverUnitBinding>>>(test);
Console.WriteLine(x?.Keys?.Count);
```

[image]

Another option, though maybe not the best route unless this makes sense for your data model, would be to have the `GetDriverBindingsResponse` simply inherit the `Dictionary<string, List<DriverUnitBinding>>` class as below.

```
public class GetDriverBindingsResponse : Dictionary<string, List<DriverUnitBinding>>
{ }
```

Comment: That sounds easier than writing a converter.  Let me try it

Comment: Definitely easier than a converter.

Comment: Works very well.  I used this method because the Response object also needs to implement the Interface to be accepted by the ResponseHandler.  `public class GetDriverBindingsResponse : Dictionary<string, List<DriverUnitBinding>> ,  IWialonApiResponseObject`